# comparing two date and creating output

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have two field named `creation_date` and `expiry_date`. I want to create a row on my table name status, if a user has passed expiry date the output must be expired and if the user haven't passed expiry date the output must be active

```
<th>
    <div>
        <?php echo get_phrase('status');?>
    </div>
</th>

<td>    
    <div class="badge badge-<?php if ($expiry_date < $creation_date) {
    echo 'Still Active';
    }
    else

    if ($expiration_date == $creation_date) {
    echo 'Still Active';
    }

    else {
    echo 'Time Expired';
    };?>">
    </div>
    <?php echo $row['status'];?>
</td>
```

Comment: Is `$expiration_date` and `$expiry_date` are same???

Answer (score 0):

Dont create such a field as it will almost always be incorrect unless you run a job to update the status field every few minutes.

Make your staus check dynamic by doing the data comparison you mention whenever you need to know if the status is Expired.